# Use Normalizr with deeply nested array in JSON

Tags: javascript, normalizr

I'm struggling to find a way to normalize this deeply nested JSON from an API response. Most documentation and resources have examples with a relatively flat structure.

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": "websites",
    "type": "table",
    "attributes": {
      "data": [
        {
          "name": "facebook.com",
          "id": "1",
          ...
        },
        {
          "name": "google.com",
          "id": "2",
          ...
        },
        {
          "name": "twitter.com",
          "id": "3",
          ...
        {
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

My desired output would be:

```
{
  entities: {
    "1": {
      "name": "facebook.com",
      "id": "1",
      ...
    },
    "2": {
      "name": "google.com",
      "id": "2",
      ...
    },
    "3": {
      "name": "twitter.com",
      "id": "3",
      ...
    }
  },
  results: ["1", "2", "3"]
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what mean by 'normalize'?

Comment: @Mark_M I believe the OP is referring to that output of: [Normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr)

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted a sample of how you wanted the "normalized" output to appear.

Comment: @StvnBrkdll updated.